# What are the "setup" Events in Windows Event Viewer Logging?

Tags: logging, event-viewer

I'm getting more familiar with the Windows Event Viewer for a recent IT job, and I'm unsure about what "setup" events are being logged in the Windows Event Viewer.

The MS documentation says it logs any action that occurs during installation, but does that mean installation of any software or installations related to the Windows OS itself -- i.e. driver updates, windows updates?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it does... You could be sure about that by reading those logs, couldn't you?

Comment: Hi @LeonardoAlvesMachado, yes you are right and I did which is what led me to want more "official" clarification. It seems for any documentation out there, people just seem to focus on the security/application log descriptions. Thanks for your help though.